Azure Communication Service for video call - Feature is not defined
With Azure communication Calling library I tried to get network quality.
const { CallClient, VideoStreamRenderer, LocalVideoStream } = require('@azure/communication-calling');
const { AzureCommunicationTokenCredential } = require('@azure/communication-common');
const { AzureLogger, setLogLevel } = require("@azure/logger");

I tried this 2 codes but I have the same error "feature is not defined".
EDIT : I put feature's code in the subscribeToCall function.
Did I forget to import something?
EDIT FOR MORE DETAILS :
My function to subscribe a call when start or accept.
subscribeToCall = (call) => {
    try {
        // Subscribe to call's 'stateChanged' event for value changes.
        call.on('stateChanged', async () => {
            // If ringing / Connected / Disconnected ...
        });

        call.on('isLocalVideoStartedChanged', () => {
            console.log(`------------- isLocalVideoStarted changed: ${call.isLocalVideoStarted}`);
        });
        call.localVideoStreams.forEach(async (lvs) => {
            localVideoStream = lvs;
            await displayLocalVideoStream();
        });
        call.on('localVideoStreamsUpdated', e => {
            e.added.forEach(async (lvs) => {
                localVideoStream = lvs;
                await displayLocalVideoStream();
            });
            e.removed.forEach(lvs => {
               removeLocalVideoStream();
            });
        });
        call.remoteParticipants.forEach(remoteParticipant => {
            subscribeToRemoteParticipant(remoteParticipant);
        });
        // Subscribe to the call's 'remoteParticipantsUpdated' event to be
        // notified when new participants are added to the call or removed from the call.
        call.on('remoteParticipantsUpdated', e => {
            // Subscribe to new remote participants that are added to the call.
            e.added.forEach(remoteParticipant => {
                subscribeToRemoteParticipant(remoteParticipant)
            });
            // Unsubscribe from participants that are removed from the call
            e.removed.forEach(remoteParticipant => {
                console.log('Remote participant removed from the call.');
            });
        });

        // CALL FEATURE TESTS ::::::::
        // First example
        /*const userFacingDiagnostics = call.feature(Features.UserFacingDiagnostics);

        userFacingDiagnostics.media.on("diagnosticChanged", (diagnosticInfo) => {
          console.log(diagnosticInfo);
        });

        userFacingDiagnostics.network.on("diagnosticChanged", (diagnosticInfo) => {
           console.log(diagnosticInfo);
        });*/

        // Second example

        /*call.feature(Features.UserFacingDiagnostics).network.on('diagnosticChanged', (diagnosticInfo) => {
            if (diagnosticInfo.diagnostic === 'networkReceiveQuality') {
                if (diagnosticInfo.value === DiagnosticQuality.Bad) {
                    console.log("Network quality = BAD");
                } else if (diagnosticInfo.value === DiagnosticQuality.Poor) {
                    console.log("Network quality = POOR");
                } else if (diagnosticInfo.value === DiagnosticQuality.Good) {
                    console.log("Network quality = GOOD");
                }
            }
        });*/


    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

EDIT 2024/04/24
First example source link : Stackoverflow - Can't load Features.Diagnostics
Second example source link : networkReceiveQuality, UFD

Can you check this MS DOC.

Do I have to subscribe to Azure monitoring (diagnostic) to have access to the features?

No, Azure monitoring (diagnostic) subscription is not required for access to the features.

Can you provide your complete code and more details that how you are trying to get network quality?

I edited my question with the subscribeToCall function, I hope that's enough.

where did use call.feature any reference you found about Features

I'm sorry I don't understand your question (even with the translation).

I am asking about features use used in your code . where did find it and any u found reference about it.

Ok I edited my post by putting the links to the sources

The error "feature is not defined" indicates that the Features object is not recognized within the scope of your code.
A features object should be used like this:
const callQualityApi = call.api(Features.Diagnostics);
callQualityApi.network.on('diagnosticChanged', diagnosticChangedListener);
callQualityApi.media.on('diagnosticChanged', diagnosticChangedListener);

To enable Call Diagnostics for your Azure Communication Services Resource, follow these steps:

Create an Azure Log Analytics workspace.
Add diagnostic settings for your resource. You can do this by following the instructions provided here. Make sure to enable logs via Diagnostic Settings in Azure Monitor.



When adding a diagnostic setting choose "allLogs" to collect all logs and Metrics.
Select Destination Details as stream the logs to a Log Analytics workspace and save.


Once you've set up Diagnostic Settings, you can access Call Diagnostics from any Azure Communication Services Resource in your Azure portal.

Navigate to your Azure Communication Services Resource and locate the "Monitoring" section on the left side of the interface.
Select "Call Diagnostics" from the options available.

The sample code below is Azure Communication Services calling SDK in Node.js to set up event handlers and listeners for various call and network diagnostic events. It checks for DiagnosticQuality.Bad, DiagnosticQuality.Poor, and DiagnosticQuality.Good.

The code for Azure Communication Services Call Diagnostics feature for web applications is taken from this reference doc

const { CallClient, VideoStreamRenderer, LocalVideoStream, Features } = require('@azure/communication-calling');
const { AzureCommunicationTokenCredential } = require('@azure/communication-common');
const { AzureLogger, setLogLevel } = require("@azure/logger");


const subscribeToCall = (call) => {
    try {
       
        call.on('stateChanged', async () => {
            // If ringing / Connected / Disconnected ...
        });

        call.on('isLocalVideoStartedChanged', () => {
            console.log(`------------- isLocalVideoStarted changed: ${call.isLocalVideoStarted}`);
        });
        call.localVideoStreams.forEach(async (lvs) => {
            localVideoStream = lvs;
            await displayLocalVideoStream();
        });
        call.on('localVideoStreamsUpdated', e => {
            e.added.forEach(async (lvs) => {
                localVideoStream = lvs;
                await displayLocalVideoStream();
            });
            e.removed.forEach(lvs => {
               removeLocalVideoStream();
            });
        });
        call.remoteParticipants.forEach(remoteParticipant => {
            subscribeToRemoteParticipant(remoteParticipant);
        });
      
        call.on('remoteParticipantsUpdated', e => {
          
            e.added.forEach(remoteParticipant => {
                subscribeToRemoteParticipant(remoteParticipant)
            });
           
            e.removed.forEach(remoteParticipant => {
                console.log('Remote participant removed from the call.');
            });
        });

        
        call.api(Features.Diagnostics).network.on('diagnosticChanged', (diagnosticInfo) => {
            console.log(diagnosticInfo);
      
        });

      
        call.api(Features.UserFacingDiagnostics).network.on('diagnosticChanged', (diagnosticInfo) => {
            if (diagnosticInfo.diagnostic === 'networkReceiveQuality') {
                if (diagnosticInfo.value === DiagnosticQuality.Bad) {
                    console.log("Network quality = BAD");
                } else if (diagnosticInfo.value === DiagnosticQuality.Poor) {
                    console.log("Network quality = POOR");
                } else if (diagnosticInfo.value === DiagnosticQuality.Good) {
                    console.log("Network quality = GOOD");
                }
            }
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}





Sorry, I validated the answer before testing.
I did everything you indicated.
I had an error "api not defined", so I modified the code with call.feature(Features.UserFacingDiagnostics).network.on('diagnosticChanged', (diagnosticInfo), there is no more error but nothing is recorded in Call Diagnostics and no information is displayed in the console.

@usualuser  please check this doc. console.log. it took hardly 1 hour to reflect .

It's okay if nothing shows up in console.log.
What really interests me is the “Call Diagnostic” in Azure.
Do I need to enable “Archive to a storage account”?
The documentation concerns a deprecated version, maybe that's why "api is not defined".

where do want to enable “Archive to a storage account”?

In Diagnostic Settings (your second screenshot).

Ok . Create Azure storage, use it as a Destination and the log will be stored in $logs

In fact, no need to activate "Archive to a storage account" to retrieve the data in the Call Diagnostic.
It's just that the data is visible only after a few hours (apparently 5 hours), which is surprising. Thanks.

Great to know it .
